# tomcat context file get removed when auto deploy war

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

Application is spring boot package as WAR.

I have 2 context file in following path

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost
```

Each context has Parameter in it, with use to define the parameter that is used by the application, example I have different environment one is appname and appname-dev for development environement.

The problem is the context file get removed if I auto deploy the war file.

```
<Context reloadable="false"> does not work.
```

Comment: I'd wonder why you don't consider deploying as an executable JAR.  No need for Tomcat anymore.  Just need Spring Boot running on a JVM.

Comment: If jar have to run it in windows service. I am using windows server.

Comment: No idea why that's germane.  If you can launch a JVM on Windows, you can run an executable JAR.  Last time I used Windows I was able to run Java.

Comment: Yea able to run using jar, but you need to run either command or register as service to start it automtically.

Comment: "Register as a service" - that's the wrong way to do it.  Not sure what you're doing.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to run this on a personal machine.  There are lots of hosting services out there.  Perhaps you should consider one of those.